# Changing quantity units on certain products in BigCommerce

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

Site: www.peekaboopatternshop.com

Theme: Barcelona Red v. 1.0.1

Stencil

The shop is selling both physical and digital products, and I need the quantity unit to display differently. For instance, if someone is buying fabric, the quantity box should have options like "1/2 yard, 1 yard, 1.5 yards" etc. But for a digital file I want to the quantity box to just have a standard options "1,2,3".

I played around with product options, but I can't figure out how to tie that into the inventory - if someone orders 2 yards of fabric, I need it to take 4 units off my available inventory (inventory for fabric is tracked in 1/2 yards), and I didn't see any way for my product options to affect my inventory unless I get into SKUs, which didn't seem relevant since I don't have variations available for each product.

On a separate note, I also can't seem to get the Quantity option to change from a box to a dropdown.

Comment: Regarding the second part of this question: "On a separate note, I also can't seem to get the Quantity option to change from a box to a dropdown." This feature is available in the older Blueprint themes, but not in Stencil.

Answer (score 0):

To have the inventory take off the correct number of units, you would need to setup the product for customers to purchase using the smallest possible unit.

So a customer would have to purchase per the 1/2 yard. Then the stock would be setup as normal. And it would deduct one for every 1/2 yard purchased.

Currently physical and downloadable are treated as separate products on the store.

There are several options:
1. Sell the physical and digital separate
2. Work with a developer to create a custom product where both are available.
3. On the product add a product option that customers can select to have someone email them the digital product later. You can also add price change rules to increase the price based on the option picked. 
4. There is a app in the BigCommerce Marketplace called [FetchApp](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/fetchapp/) that might allow this functionality also.

If you still have questions please reach out to [BigCommerce support](https://support.bigcommerce.com/contact).